# DateTime.ToString format inconsistent between Web App and Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

We are experiencing weird behaviour between a web application and windows service when trying to perform a `ToString()` on a `DateTime` value. 
See the example below.

```
DateTime parsedReportDate;
reportDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
reportDateWithSlash = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
if (DateTime.TryParse(MyDateValue, out parsedReportDate))
{    
    reportDate = parsedReportDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    reportDateWithSlash = parsedReportDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

--reportDateWithSlash on Web Application: 28/03/2017
--reportDateWithSlash on Windows Service: 28-03-2017
```

The Windows Service calls the same function as the Web Application does, so why is the formatting different then?

Comment: Probably a culture issue. Try `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: and solve by `Regex` and `TryParseExact`

Comment: @Pikoh That could be confirmed by looking at the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in both environments

Comment: @Pikoh, that indeed fixed the issue. Please answer.

Comment: @bradbury9 yes, but anyway using `InvariantCulture` would solve the problem no matter what, no need to check anything.

Comment: @Pikoh agree, IMHO it would make the code less prone to errors if working with strings from different cultures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must come from having different cultures. Using the [DateTime.ToString (String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) overload with the [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) property should solve the problem:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

The formatting of dates to strings uses a [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object to know what format to use.

Each [`Thread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) has a [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can find out what `CultureInfo` the current `Thread` is set by getting the current `Thread` using [`Thread.CurrentThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread(v=vs.110).aspx) and then inspecting it's `Thread.CurrentCulture` property.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dsA3VT

Output: `en-US`

You can set the `CultureInfo` for the the `Thread`, or pass it with each call to `ToString`.

### Setting Thread.CultureInfo

You can set the `Thread.CultureInfo` using the same property as you use to read it.

```
Thread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
```

Unfortunately .Net Fiddle doesn't support changing thread properties.

I didn't know  this, but bradbury9 pointed out that since .net 4.6 you can set the [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) property as well.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
```

Unfortunately .Net Fiddle doesn't support changing the culture this way either.

### Passing CultureInfo to ToString

['DateTime.ToString'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576(v=vs.110).aspx) has overloads which can take an [`IFormatProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), and `CultureInfo` impliments `IFormatProvider`.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-gb"));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qkS5HF

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));     
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-us")));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
en-US
03/28/2017 09:43:49
3/28/2017 9:43:49 AM
```

Comment: Or use the InvariantCulture in the code so it behaves in all environments the same regardless of the current culture used.

Comment: You use the Invariant culture if that is the formatting you want to use. If you wanted to use say German style formatting then Invariant wouldn't be what you want.

Comment: I would use invariant cultures for the code and specific cultures only for displaying purposes. That way different frontends using different cultures and sharing the codebase could be used in a pretty straigforward way in case it were neccesary, but that is my personal opinion tho.

Comment: Yep, that's a good option that helps reduce the chance of errors. Thanks for the suggestion about setting CultureInfo.CurrentCulture. The edit got declined so I added it myself.

Answer (score 0):

it may be what is calling the Windows service is formatting the date. the code certainly is clear enough. Try debugging the windows service by attaching to the running process and see what it generates. If your service consumer is a web app, look at F12 developer tools and see what is getting sent back int he response stream.