# C# Windows Application DateTime does not work when Deployed

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am getting an expiry date from an XML file and then convert it to a DateTime. This works in **debug** mode. However after it gets deployed it returns an error.

```
public LabelInfo ParseLabelsingalData(XmlNode Llist)
{
   LabelInfo labelinfor = new LabelInfo();
   labelinfor.ID = Llist.Attributes["Name"].Value;
   labelinfor.Name = Llist.Attributes["Name"].Value;
   labelinfor.ExpiryDate = 
   Convert.ToDateTime(Llist.Attributes["ExpiryDate"].Value); 
}
```

I am getting date from xml like "31/01/2018" return error is - string was not recognized as a valide datetime. in this case i found a solution and i try to convert datetime using this function.

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dtime, format, 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out 
Temdate))
{
    labelinfor.MinimumExpiryDate = Temdate;
}
```

So however when I equal this out value to object variable it's show date and month swap.

```
labelinfor.MinimumExpiryDate = Temdate; 
SysLog.WriteLog("Trace ExpiryDate - " + labelinfor.ExpiryDate);-  01/31/2018
```

Comment: Is this a console app? Website? What country are you based in? What date format / locale does your login use on your local PC? What date format is used when running it unsuccessfully?

Comment: Also, what is the **exact** value of `Llist.Attributes["ExpiryDate"].Value`? Please also show a fragment of the XML document including **that specific date**.

Comment: this appliction is windows service application . xml value - Llist.Attributes["ExpiryDate"].Value = 31/01/2018  but when i run this service in my laptop it;s work. but when i deploy in server return a error. server datetime is US format.

Comment: In that case, the code is working as expected. The logged date looks like that is because your server is running US date format (which puts month before day). You need to either change its locale (to not use US date format) or use `labelinfor.ExpiryDate.ToString("dateformatyouwanthere")` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime.ToString format inconsistent between Web App and Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065709/datetime-tostring-format-inconsistent-between-web-app-and-windows-service)

Comment: If whoever was constructing this XML followed the common pattern and use ISO 8601 date format, this wouldn't be such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Tempdate.ToString(format);

const string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
//31/01/2018
Console.WriteLine( DateTime.ParseExact("31/01/2018",format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None).ToString(format));
Console.ReadLine();
```